# Which are the default settings of the key repeat rate?

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard

I tried adjusting my repeat rate for the keyboard, on Snow Leopard, by using the following:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0
defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 7
```

I wish to set the InitialKeyRepeat value to its default setting, how could I go about doing that? Could someone check and let me know the value of the InitialKeyRepeat they are using?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
defaults delete NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat
defaults delete NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat
```

and reboot.